# Kohana 3.1 Validation Questions

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

Few fast questions as I'm unable to find such info in docs.

1. How to validate a single checkbox while creating user using Auth's create_user()?
2. Any ideas how to validate captcha?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (isset($_POST['captcha_response']))
{
    if (Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha_response']))
 { // you code here 'captcha_response' implies the input name of captcha
}}
```

I would prefer Validation using client side scripting language such as jquery and not with server side